# Data Transfer from C program to C#

Tags: c#, c, ipc

I wrote a touchpad program in C that provide x,y information of the touchpad. Now, I want to transfer that X,Y values to a C# program. I tried to write the information to a file and read using C#. But, as C program blocked the text file, I was getting the following error:

The process cannot access the file 'C:\simpletpinfo\data.txt' because it is being used by another process.

I don't have much idea about the socket programming and i couldn't run the examples of socket programming that are in the web. (I am using visual studio 2008, may be that doesn't support sys/socket.h and other files). please help me in this regards.

Comment: sys/socket.h is rather a POSIX API, not really for windows.

Comment: Windows has its own version of the sockets API (Winsock) that is pretty close to the original.  Doing a quick search for this term might help you get the data out of the C program a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Interprocess Communication, IPC. There are many ways, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page describes all the different ways on Windows and when to use which.

In my opinion I think you should consider using [Data Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648710%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. is it possible to write a text file continuously in C and read the values from that file using C# concurrently.

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kztecsys%28VS.80%29.aspx  
But why don't you want to use Data Copy?  
BTW: It's probably possible to read your x,y information directly from your C# program. Nearly everything which is possible in C shall be possible in C# to, AFAIK.

Comment: Unless you want to preserve every bit that is sent from one program to another, there is no good reason to use a file for IPC, much less one formatted in text.  Really, read the pages Polybos linked to.

Comment: I tried with the data copy and used the following code. But in the C# window, I was getting some garbage values. Not sure where to fix:

got the code from the following link:http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/using-wm-copydata-to-send-message-from-c-to-c-553567.html

Comment: So what are you getting in your C# window and what did ou sent? I don't have access to a windows machine so I unfortunately cannot test it myself :(

Comment: hi Polybos, i fixed that problem. Now it's reading data from C#. but my main goal was to transfer the data on windows mobile application which supports C#. Yesterday, I have found that it doesn't support in windows mobile. here i post another question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590005/copydatastruct-in-windows-mobile-5-0